# Library not loaded MacOS

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

estoy trabajando desde un Mac m1 con sistema Ventura13.6 y al tratar de crear un nuevo proyecto de laravel me aparece este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También me ocurre al probar otros comandos, he reinstalado brew pero el problema persiste.

Que puedo tratar de hacer? Y porque puede estar ocurriendo este problema?

Muchas gracias de antemano